# Find electronics in wilderness; or, "I dropped my cell phone in the woods!"

Tags: electrical-engineering, metals, rf-electronics, radar

Imagine I was working in the woods and dropped my cell phone somewhere in a large area where it is now hidden beneath dense vegetation.  By calling it I confirm that either it has powered off or its battery is dead.  How can I find it?

A consumer metal detector (induction magnetometer) will easily find it *if* I can get within a few feet of it.  But there must be more efficient means of finding electronics in a wide wilderness area given their unique and unnatural characteristics.  For example:

1. They contain dense, refined metals.  There is easily more copper, nickel, and perhaps a few other elements in a phone than in an acre of wilderness almost anywhere.
2. They contain antennas.  Even when powered off, the electronic structures are there to receive and transmit signals efficiently in a particular spectrum.

Can radar be used to discriminate either of these characteristics and provide a practical means of scanning a large area to zero in on the device?  Are there existing systems that do this?

Comment: Enable “find my phone”, then attach phone to belt with piece of string... prevention is better than cure...

Comment: @SolarMike: The anecdote is for illustration.  The general question is, "What technologies can detect unpowered electronic devices that may be concealed from view but present in a large area where no (or few) other artificial devices would be expected to clutter any signal that may be used for detection and location?"

Comment: Then you should edit your question to improve it and remove excess information...